# Самопечатающийся текст на JavaScript, улучшение скрипта

Tags: javascript

Вопрос состоит в том, как можно изменить данный скрипт, чтобы можно было добавлять элементы в HTML код и в добавленном элементе скрипт работал и тест самопечатался, чтобы я мог добавить div или h1,и по id вписать туда текст, после чего на странице он будет самопечататься.

```js
function animateText(id, text, i) {
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = text.substring(0, i);
  i++;
  if (i > text.length) {
    i = 0;
    return;
  }
  setTimeout("animateText('" + id + "','" + text + "'," + i + ")", 70);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body onload='animateText("dynamic-text", "Как создать свой сайт", 0);'>
<span id='dynamic-text'></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: а что мешает вызвать эту функцию с новыми id?

Comment: можете написать где именно пример.вы имеете ввиду добавить текстовый элемент на страницу и к нему так же прописать onload но с новым id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используя jQuery:

```js
function animateDynamicText() {
  function recurciveUpdateText($el, text, symbolsCount) {
    $el.text(text.substring(0, symbolsCount));
    if (symbolsCount >= text.length) {
      return;
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
      recurciveUpdateText($el, text, ++symbolsCount);
    }, 70);
  }
  
  $('.dynamic-text:not([data-intialized])').each(function () {
    let $this = $(this);
    $this.attr('data-intialized', true);
    recurciveUpdateText($this, $this.text(), 0);
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  animateDynamicText();
});

$('#addAnimatedText').click(function() {
  let newDiv= $('<div class="dynamic-text">Как заказать разработку сайта у профессионалов</div>');
  $('body').append(newDiv);
  animateDynamicText();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="addAnimatedText">Add animated text</button>
<div class='dynamic-text'>Как создать свой сайт</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ) но понимаете,мне на сайте нужно будет целый листок текста,чтобы он сам печатался и я думал можно ли не в скрипте писать сам текст,а в div элементе или любом єлементе,у вас в скрипте выводит - , "Как заказать разработку сайта у профессионалов" он выводит данный текст из скрипта,а можно ли сделать так,чтобы тект выводило с html элемента,вот я сейчас создам текстовый елемент h1 ,и текст который там будет чтобы он так же самопечатался,вот в чем был вопрос

Comment: @ike77 докидывайте класс `dynamic-text` на требуемый элемент и дергайте `animateDynamicText()`

Comment: спасибо,сейчас буду внедрять